# Trouble storing image path into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading, imageurl

I'm having troubles understanding the storing of images ***file path*** into MySQL database.
But it is storing the images details as well as moving the image file into directory. I've tried many approaches but no luck. I'm a PHP novice.

***Question:***
How do I properly capture and store the path to the image into MySQL?

***Reference Link:***
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/uploading-files-to-the-server-using-php.aspx

***Also:*** Please suggest any better coding practices overall for consideration. Much appreciated!

```
//MYSQL TABLE
CREATE TABLE `userimages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ipath` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

***Here are my error messages.***

Notice: Undefined variable: path in /useradmin-processor.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: ipath in /useradmin-processor.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined variable: path in /useradmin-processor.php on line 59

```
// IMAGE UPLOAD FILE
if(isset($_POST['imagesupload'])) {
    /*
    Note: The below code will upload the image to the images folder.
    Then store the image name in your database. When you want to show the
    image, just append the image name(taken from database) to the image path
    and paste it in the <img>
    */
    $imageFileName       =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["name"];
    $tmpImageFileName    =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["tmp_name"];
    $imageSize           =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["size"];
    $imageType           =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["type"];

    move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName,"images/".$imageFileName);

    /*
    Note: You can make sure that the images are not overritten by checking
    if there is a different image with the same file name, by using the
    below code prevents overwriting of images due to same Image names.
    You have to store the new Image name in the database.
    */
    $newImageFileName    =   $imageFileName;

    loop1:

    if(!file_exists("images/".$newImageFileName)){
        move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName, $path.$newImageFileName);
    } else {
        $newImageFileName .= "_1";
        goto loop1;
    }

    /*
    Note: store the image details into the database and make the connection.
    */
    $params = array(
        ':$path'=>$_POST['ipath']
    );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userimages ( name, size, type, ipath ) ".
    "VALUES ( '$imageFileName', '$imageSize', '$imageType', '$path' )";

    // the connection to db
    executeSQL($sql, $params);
}
```

Comment: image path should be TEXT or BLOB and not varchar, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: Far as I can see, `$path` is undefined, which everything follows from thereon. Plus, what are you trying to do here => `:$path`, bind?

Comment: You need placeholders `?` or `:var` when binding (if that's what you're trying to do), and yours doesn't contain any. Your question is unclear as to what should do what, and where, while using God-knows-which-function(s). You probably meant to do `( name, size, type, :ipath )` - Really hard to say.

Comment: I was trying to follow this, which is what it originally was in a tutorial: $query = "INSERT INTO upload2 (name, size, type, path ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$filePath')";
...... where as, what I was doing was taking my snippet of code as a starting point where I was storing user profile type text vs a path. So I'm a bit stumped here.

Comment: @Grasper, he's storing the image's path (file name), not the contents of the image, on his row in `userimages`. `VARCHAR(250)` should be a perfectly good data type for a path name.

Comment: @OllieJones that's exactly what I'm trying to do here. Because I want to then use that file name to obviously display the image to the user after it's uploaded. I most certainly don't want to store the image itself into the database.

Comment: One question remains; where is `$path` defined; or why isn't it defined/shown?

Comment: @JonnyB -- you have defined your ipath column as a blob / binary large object in your table. should be varchar().

Comment: That still qualifies as being undefined. - Edit: you've deleted your comment in regards to `$path` which was `move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName, $path.$newImageFileName);` in response to my comment.

Comment: I think it's this line `$params = array(
        ':$path'=>$_POST['ipath']
    );` which should be changed to just `$path=$_POST['ipath'];` which is why you're getting an undefined variable, and make sure your form element is named `ipath`

Comment: @Fred-ii- move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName, $path.$newImageFileName); I thought this was saying my $path becomes part of $newImageFileName... Then later on assumed I needed to say ok now... $path you need to actually go into my database field called ipath.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way, unless you're binding which you're not, and even then. See my [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726125/trouble-storing-image-path-into-mysql#comment43864909_27726125). `$path` doesn't get defined just because it's concatenated inside `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Did you notice in the tutorial how the file path is defined `$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;`? It works in conjunction with `$uploadDir = 'C:/webroot/upload/';` and `$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];` something you're not doing.

Comment: @Grasper FYI, you shouldn't be storing images in a MySQL database. The answer to storing them isn't "use blob" if that had actually been his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

I added that in and now it all works. I also changed how I'm connecting to the database. I'm sure it could be done better as I now have this hanging on in the code. $params = array();

```
// IMAGE UPLOAD
$uploadDir = 'images/';

if(isset($_POST['imagesupload'])) {

    $imageFileName       =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["name"];
    $tmpImageFileName    =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["tmp_name"];
    $imageSize           =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["size"];
    $imageType           =   $_FILES["imageFileName"]["type"];

    //move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName,"images/".$imageFileName);

    $filePath = $uploadDir . $imageFileName;

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName, $filePath);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading file";
        exit;
    }

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $imageFileName = addslashes($imageFileName);
        $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
    }

    $newImageFileName    =   $imageFileName;

    loop1:

    if(!file_exists("images/".$newImageFileName)){
        move_uploaded_file($tmpImageFileName, $filePath.$newImageFileName);
    } else {
        $newImageFileName .= "_1";
        goto loop1;
    }

    $params = array();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userimages ( name, size, type, ipath ) ".
    "VALUES ( '$imageFileName', '$imageSize', '$imageType', '$filePath' )";
    executeSQL($sql, $params);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out. Happy ♫ New Year!